# FsJobArchivist unable to create jobid json as a directory with name that of jobid exists

Tags: apache-flink, high-availability

I have a flink cluster running on kubernetes with two jobmanagers and two taskmanagers. I have also configured zookeeper for high-availability mode for the flink cluster. I am able to run the jobs in HA mode.

The problem, that I am facing is that when the job get's completed, and the FsJobArchivist is trying to archive the job, I get the error

`Failed to archive job: File already exists`

When I check inside the folder to where the property `jobmanager.archive.fs.dir` is set to in flink-conf.yaml, I see that a folder with the name similar to that of jobid already exists. For e.g., if `jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: /tmp/flink/completed-jobs` and the jobid is `6o3w487562934587`, then a directory `/tmp/flink/completed-jobs/6o3w487562934587` exists, hence, the json creation of the archived job fails with the above error. The `/tmp/flink/completed-jobs` is a volume mounted to a nfs server.

However, I do not see this problem, when I run my job on flink cluster in non-ha mode and I see a json file with name, that of jobid exists that the historyserver is able to read.

Has anyone encountered this problem? If so, what is the solution to the same? Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Edits:

On further investigation, I see that with checkpointing enabled, the checkpointing data is being written to all the volumeMounts. For e.g. if my flink-conf.yaml looks like:

```
jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: /tmp/flink/completed-jobs
historyserver.archive.fs.dir: /tmp/flink/completed-jobs
state.checkpoints.dir: /tmp/flink/checkpoints
state.savepoints.dir: /tmp/flink/savepoints
```

then the checkpoint data (chk-1, chk-2...) are written in all the directories.